# Symfony Finder: Get all the files with a specific extension and all the directories within a specific directory

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I am using the `Symfony Finder` to get all the files with a certain extension and all the directories in a specific directory.

```
    protected function getDirectoryContent(string $directory): array
    {
        $finder = Finder::create()
            ->in($directory)
            ->depth(0)
            ->name(['*.json', '*.php'])
            ->sortByName();

        return iterator_to_array($finder, true);
    }
```

In this way, this method returns only all the files with extension `.php` or `.json` within a certain directory. For example, the directory structure I am looking in is the following:

```
/my/directory/
├── A
├── A.JSON
├── anotherfile.kas
├── file0.ds
├── file1.json
├── file2.php
├── file3.php
├── B
└── C
```

`A`, `B` and `C` are directories.

When I pass the above `directory path` as the `$directory` argument in the method I showed above, I get an array with the following elements:

```
file1.json
file2.php
file3.php
```

Great!, but my question is, how could I also add all the `directories` to the resulting array? My expectations are to get an array like the following:

```
A
B
C
file1.json
file2.php
file3.php
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In you case, you speak to finder:

- Please add recursive directory iterator with depth 0 (it's OK, we want to search only in root)
- Please add file name iterator (it's wrong, because you find only **files**).

As result it's wrong, because these two rules contradict each other - because you want search only files.

But, symfony finder can use `CallbackIterator` with filter model. In this situation you can add many rules or condition. In you example:

```
namespace Acme;

use Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder;
use Symfony\Component\Finder\SplFileInfo;

include __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

$finder = Finder::create();

$finder
    ->in(__DIR__)
    ->depth(0)
    ->filter(static function (SplFileInfo $file) {
        return $file->isDir() || \preg_match('/\.(php|json)$/', $file->getPathname());
    });

print_r(\iterator_to_array($finder));
```

In this case, you speak:

- Please find only in root.
- Please check - or file or match by my pattern.

Comment: Thanks! @ZhukV, I had asked the same question in the symfony repository on github, a user gave me an idea, but I did not see it as a very good idea, since with his solution, I would be iterating 2 times each directory. https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/38949#issuecomment-720137475. It seems to me that your solution is much more efficient, since it would go through the directory only once, and then filter the resulting array. Thank you very much again.